# What is the condition to create a closure?

Tags: javascript, closures

In my naive concept, a closure is simply a function return by another function, which preserve the scope of the outer function after it returns:

```js
var factory = function(y){
   var x = 2;
   return function(){
      console.log(x+y);
   }
}

var closure1 = factory(2);
closure1(); // output 4

var closure2 = factory(10);
closure1(); // output 4
closure2(); // output 12
```

Though I do not understand why adding event handler in loop will create closures? (As shown in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures#Creating_closures_in_loops_A_common_mistake)) The event handler does not explicitly be returned, this is not the concern in this problem.

---

Then I came across another [page](http://unscriptable.com/2011/10/02/closures-for-dummies-or-why-iife-closure/), and at around *Code snippet #2:*, it said

> The onclick function would create a closure if it referenced variables in its scope, but it doesn’t.

Does that mean that in the loop

`nodes[i].onclick = function () { return false; };` is not closures

But if I changed it into

`nodes[i].onclick = function () { console.log(i); return false; };`

Then it becomes closure?

---

Combined the parts above, my concept to create a closure are

1. It needs to be a function returned in another function, or the callback function which attached in another function
2. The inner function **MUST** somehow access outer function's scope

Is it true that a closure is created iff 1 & 2 are satisfied?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> a closure is simply a function return by another function, which preserve the scope of the outer function after it returns

Close.

It is a function which still has references pointing to it after the function that it was created inside has finished.

Returning it is one way to preserve a reference to it.

> Though I do not understand why adding event handler in loop will create closures?

The reference is passed to the event handling code. This preserves it after the function which passed it there has finished.

---

> Does that mean that in the loop …

Yes, it does.

---

> It needs to be a function returned in another function, or the callback function which attached in another function

No. The reference can go anywhere, so long as it is preserved.

```js
var obj = {};

function create() {

  var foo = 1;

  obj.bar = function() {
    console.log(foo++);
  };
}

create();

obj.bar();
obj.bar();
obj.bar();
obj.bar();
```

> The inner function MUST somehow access outer function's scope

Yes